# Safari and Firefox display jagged lines using Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having a hard time getting smooth lines drawing with Canvas, but only in Safari and Firefox. Chrome draws smoothly. It looks like this in Safari:

[screenshot http://jacobharris.org/screenshot.jpg](http://jacobharris.org/screenshot.jpg)

This is my JavaScript:

```
function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
    if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = color_selected;
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        if (lastX == 0 && lastY ==0){
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        }else{
            ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        }
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    lastX = x; lastY = y;
}}
```

I'm making sure to choose "round" for lineJoin and lineCap. Not sure what else I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
ctx.closePath();
```

and it should work.

There is no need to call `closePath()` on a single line as you will only create an overlapping instance on top of it. Safari seem to not be able to handle this very good (implementation dependent, but a guess would be it's way of setting the bits - low-level wise; where there is an overlap in same path instance it seem to get xor'ed or not'ed when rasterized).

**[FIDDLE WITH MODIFIED CODE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/TL5UT/)**